# html5 canvas bezier curve - how to construct a reflection?

Tags: canvas, bezier

If I build a bezier curve using control.bezierCurveTo, I would like to programmatically draw the mirror reflection of this curve. I have the start/end and control points for first curve. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To mirror your points around the x axis, it's simply the same points but with negative y values.

```
(1,4) (-2,2) (4,-6) ==> (1,-4) (-2,-2) (4,6)
```

Same applies for the y axis, but use negative x values instead.

Comment: can you give same jsfiddle example of this

Answer (score 0):

Just mirror the control points around the axis of your choice.